# jQuery autocomplete filtering issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

This is my code. I am trying to search only if user enter "[" symbol. But user can enter normal words also like hello.

Example :
Hello - no need to autocomplete.
[Hello] - need to autocomplete.

Here is the [jsfiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/43d1eyqg/71/)

```js
function split(val) {
  return val.split(/,\s*/);
}

function extractLast(term) {
  return split(term).pop();
}

var availableTags = [
  "[Hello]",
  "[Hello World]",
  "[Google",
  "[New Life]",
  "[World]",
  "[Old]"
];
$("#tags").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
    response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
      availableTags, extractLast(request.term)));
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
    var terms = split(this.value);
    // remove the current input
    terms.pop();
    // add the selected item
    terms.push(ui.item.value);
    // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
    terms.push("");
    this.value = terms.join("  ");
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" jq=""></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Search: </label>
  <input type="text" id="tags" onkeypress="edValueKeyPress()" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your `source` `callback` to use `response` like below. Get `lastTerm` and check if it starts with `[` then only return filtered results else return empty which will not display any results in autocomplete.

As per comment it was not working for 2nd selection from autocomplete, you need to add `focus` `callback` which would be similar to `select` with little change that it will not have one line `terms.push("");`.

```
source: function(request, response) {
  let lastTerm = extractLast(request.term);
  if (lastTerm.trim().startsWith('[')) {
    // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
    response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, lastTerm));
  } else {
    response([]);
  }
},
focus: function(event, ui) {
  var terms = split(this.value);
  // remove the current input
  terms.pop();
  // add the selected item
  terms.push(ui.item.value); 
  // terms.push(""); <-- comment this line from select   
  this.value = terms.join(", ");
  return false;
}
```

Try it below.

```js
function split(val) {
  return val.split(/,\s*/);
}

function extractLast(term) {
  return split(term).pop();
}

var availableTags = [
  "[Hello]",
  "[Hello World]",
  "[Google",
  "[New Life]",
  "[World]",
  "[Old]"
];

$("#tags").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    let lastTerm = extractLast(request.term);
    if (lastTerm.trim().startsWith('[')) {
      // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
      response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, lastTerm));
    } else {
      response([]);
    }
  },
  focus: function(event, ui) {
     var terms = split(this.value);
    // remove the current input
    terms.pop();
    // add the selected item
    terms.push(ui.item.value);
    // terms.push(""); <-- comment this line from select
    this.value = terms.join(", ");
    return false;
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
    var terms = split(this.value);
    // remove the current input
    terms.pop();
    // add the selected item
    terms.push(ui.item.value);
    // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
    terms.push("");
    this.value = terms.join(", ");
    return false;
  }
});

function edValueKeyPress() {}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" jq=""></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Search: </label>
  <input type="text" id="tags" onkeypress="edValueKeyPress()" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but your code is working for the first word. but after that its not support. this user can enter many words with "["

Comment: For the second word user has to start with `[` and it will show autocomplete options. Isn't that what you needed?

Comment: yes that's what i need. but its not filtering second one

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check now.

Comment: Also note that in `select` you should be having `join(", ")` as `this.value = terms.join(", ");` not `this.value = terms.join("  ");`.